# How to modify variable labels in gtsummary table

Tags: r, gtsummary

As recommended in the [tutorial](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_regression.html?q=labelled#example-data-set) for `gtsummary`'s `tbl_regression` function, I am using the `labelled` package to assign attribute labels to my regression variables. However, when my regression formula includes a quadratic term, the resulting table includes the same variable label twice:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(labelled)
library(tidyverse)

df <- as_tibble(mtcars)

var_label(df) <- list( disp = "Displacement", vs = "Engine type")

c("disp", "disp + I(disp^2)") %>% 
  map(
    ~ paste("vs", .x, sep = " ~ ") %>% 
      as.formula() %>% 
      glm(data = df,
          family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>% 
      tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)) %>% 
  tbl_merge()
```

[image: Example of gtsummary table]

Is there a way to modify the label for the quadratic term in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign the label inside the `tbl_regression()` function, you'll see what you want to get.

```r
library(gtsummary)

c("disp", "disp + I(disp^2)") %>% 
  purrr::map(
    ~ paste("vs", .x, sep = " ~ ") %>% 
      as.formula() %>% 
      glm(data = mtcars, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>% 
      tbl_regression(
        exponentiate = TRUE,
        label = list(
          disp = "Displacement",
          `I(disp^2)` = "Displacement^2"
        )
      )
  ) %>%
  tbl_merge() %>%
  as_kable()
#> ✖ `I(disp^2)` terms have not been found in `x`.
```

| **Characteristic** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Displacement | 0.98 | 0.96, 0.99 | 0.002 | 0.99 | 0.92, 1.07 | 0.8 |
| Displacement^2 |  |  |  | 1.00 | 1.00, 1.00 | 0.8 |

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>